# click once application slowness issue

Tags: wpf, clickonce

We have a strange problem. We have a click-once deployed application at a customer site that is experiencing slowness. It happens every time they launch the application, regardless of whether new updates have been applied or not. So it has nothing to do with first time loading slowness. The target framework is .net 4.5 and the application itself is a wpf application.

If we execute the .exe directly from where the click-once install puts the files in, then there is no delay whatsoever.
As far as I can see there is nothing that we are doing that is special in code...that is specific to click-once installation.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

when a clickonce application starts up, it checks for updates. Where do you have the updates stored? That may be where the slowness is coming into play.

On the publish tab, under updates, you can specify how often your app will check for updates. It can check for updates after the application starts which will speed up start time, however, updates will not be installed until the next time your app runs.

Comment: the default setting is for your app to CHECK for updates. The process of checking for updates may be slowing down the startup of your app.